# How to configure VS2017 to use system CMake instead of nested one

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

Visual Studio 2017 add a new feature supporting directly open CMake project now. But it always use its own nested CMake. It's quite annoying since i can't touch that CMake. It has different version, different configuration from my usual one.

So I want to know is there a way to change this behavior, like in CLion, by assigning which CMake to use?